# How to use PHP code in HTML to generate a PDF with mPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I want generate an invoice in PDF from our PHP code. We use mPDF, but we see mPDF uses `$html` to generate PDF, meaning when our matter is stable and only in HTML, then it converts to a PDF file.

We want generate a PDF of a dynamic table of products from our database, but it always shows an error when we use PHP code in the `$html` tag.

How can we use our dynamic PHP code in HTML to generate a PDF with mPDF?

Comment: Just post some code that you tried so that someone will help you with the code

Comment: which error is reported?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mpdf library. This code works perfectly. I hope this will save your time. You can get value from another page, using post method also. Your choice.

```
<?php $student_id = $_GET['student_id']; ?>
<?php
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$html .= "
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-image: url(\"images/ok.jpg\");

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:10pt;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
td { vertical-align: top; 
    border-left: 0.6mm solid #000000;
    border-right: 0.6mm solid #000000;
    align: center;
}

p.student_id{
    padding-left : 140px;
    padding-top  : -27px;
} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--mpdf                                                                          

<p class=\"student_id\">$student_id</p>


<sethtmlpageheader name='myheader' value='on' show-this-page='1' />
<sethtmlpagefooter name='myfooter' value='on' />
mpdf-->


</body>
</html>
";

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Download *mpdf* library using *php composer*, then include the following code.

require_once **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$html = "YOUR HTML CODE HERE";

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. What **exactly** is important, and why?